# automaticaly switch between intranet and internet

Tags: intranet

at my workplace there is intranet that we use to access our local site to do office work.

occassionaly we use smartphone as modem to connect to internet to access. but when we try to access a site on internet it displays page not found. Then for this we have to temporarily disable the wired intranet. 
Then to access the intranet we have disable the wireless modem and enable intranet.
is there any way that both connections are active simultaneously and whenever we type some address it should first check local intranet and if found load it else access the internet to load website?

Comment: Is the a reason your local intranet doesn't have Internet access?  What OS are you using. This is expected behavior with Linux and Mac. I often use my phones internet (tether) as the primary and can access stuff on my home via the Ethernet. If your work has properly named addresses. It will work just fine. If you're on windows. I don't know how to help but can promise this is possible.